# Flexslider - Charging with fixed images

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, flexslider

I am using Flexslider, but while the images load and the function is not performed, it plays an image beneath the other, generating a huge scroll bar and, after running and loading the images, it runs normally.

The question is: no way to keep the images in the same position one below the other before they carry? not to generate this huge scroll bar.

The following code:

Html:

```
  <div class="sliderTrabalhe" ng-init="vm.sliderTrabalhe();">
     <ul class="slides">
      <li ng-repeat="s in vm.repeat(7) track by $index">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url('app/template/img/slider.jpg');"></div>
      </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Function:

```
vm.sliderTrabalhe = function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
       $('.sliderTrabalhe').flexslider({
       animation: "slide",
       controlNav: true
     });
   }, 1000);
 }
```

CSS:

```
 .sliderTrabalhe{
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
        @extend .largura_total;
        height: 500px;
        .image{
            height: 500px;
        }
        .flex-control-nav{
            bottom: -30px;
            left: 50px;
        }
        .flex-control-paging li a{
            background: $cinza_escuro!important; 
        }
        .flex-control-paging li a.flex-active{
            background: $vermelho!important; 
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            padding-top: 2px;
        }
        .flex-control-nav li {
            margin: 0 3px; 
        }
    }
```

The following images for better understanding:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS to remove bug:

```
.sliderTrabalhe {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sliderTrabalhe .slides > li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.sliderTrabalhe .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.sliderTrabalhe .slides:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .sliderTrabalhe .slides {
  display: block;
}
* html .sliderTrabalhe .slides {
  height: 1%;
}
.no-js .sliderTrabalhe .slides > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
.sliderTrabalhe {
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
}
.sliderTrabalhe .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.sliderTrabalhe .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.sliderTrabalhe:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: -20px;
}
.sliderTrabalhe:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sliderTrabalhe:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: -20px;
}
.sliderTrabalhe:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sliderTrabalhe .flex-direction-nav a{
  width: 19px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please upload demo of this slider. are your try  ? :

```
.image
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

and style :

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: if I remove the height of the image it does not appear: /

Comment: ok.I think there is not a css way to solve this problem. you can get background image size and then set  by js.img height and width. you can try min-height: 500; a live demo of this project can help to solve .